# Como hacer para que una imagen traida con js a html no se repita constantemente

Tags: javascript, html

quería saber como podría hacer para que la imagen que inserto con js se muestre sin repetirse, mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height: 100vw" id="imagen">
  <br /><br />IMAGEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEN
</div>
```

y en el js

```
    const imagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
function fondo() {
  const url =
    "imagen en cuestion";
  imagen.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
}
document.body.addEventListener("load", fondo);
fondo();
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Probaste a ponerle los estilos adecuados al fondo?? Por defecto la imagen de fondo se repite para cubrir la pantalla... si quieres otro comportamiento debes especificarlo tú. Para más info [tienes la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat). Por cierto, una simple búsqueda en google te habría dado unas cuantas docenas de sitios con esta misma información... Se debe investigar antes de preguntar!!